# Sorting the tensorflow dataset based on a particular column

Tags: tensorflow, sorting

My tensorflow dataset looks like this:

```
{'CUSTOMER_ID': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1110>, 'Delivery_Desc': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'DELIXY11 Dec,202113:30'>, 'PIN_CODE': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=122002>}
```

followed by 1000 lines.

I want to sort the dataset based on pincode, without converting it to pandas

Comment: Once you have created a dataset with features for 'PIN_CODE', We can use 'tf.data.Dataset' API to sort the dataset without converting it to pandas. Please Find the below code line.
#instead of 1 you have to change it according to the particular column in your dataset
`sorted_dataset = sorted(dataset, key=lambda x: x[1]`. Kindly try this and let me know if you have any concerns.